# Viewing with hand above eyes

Tags: visible-light

Some pictures of American Indians show them with a flat hand above their eyes. It seems like I heard that is because they could get a slightly sharper view of the horizon rather than just shading their eyes. Is that right? Why does that happen? Refraction?